# Error al eliminar filas específicas

Tags: r

Estoy intentando eliminar unas filas específicas de mi dataframe:

```
    species level<-dataframe
    species level:
     Site      Date    Habitat    Season    Year     Taxa
     Q1F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Artemisia_herba_alta
     Q2F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Artemisia_herba_alta
     Q4F    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Allium
     Q1P    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Artemisia_herba_alta
     Q2P    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Amaranthus
     Q4P    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Anacyclus
     Q4P    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Asparagus
     Q4P    08_09_2015  Oak     Autumn   2015-2016   Amaranthus_retroflex
```

Quiero eliminar estas filas que contengan estos nombres en la columna taxa

```
      Allium<-which(with(Specieslevel,Taxa=="Allium"))
      Amaranthus<-which(with(Specieslevel,Taxa=="Amaranthus"))
      Anacyclus<-which(with(Specieslevel,Taxa=="Anacyclus"))
```

Cuando le completo el script para que lo elimine de datraframe (Specieslevel) solo me elimina el primero que corro; en este caso Allium, dejando Anacyclus y Asparragus sin eliminarlos.

```
         Specieslevel<-Specieslevel[-Allium,]
         Specieslevel<-Specieslevel[-Amaranthus,]
         Specieslevel<-Specieslevel[-Anacyclus,]
```

¿Alguien podría decirme cual es el error que estoy cometiendo?
¿Se podría hacer esta función de una manera más rápida?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que estás borrando sobre borrado. Te explico: en tu ejemplo `Allium`, `Amaranthus` y `Anacyclus` son vectores con el número de fila dónde `Taxa` es igual a dicho valor. Luego haces:

```
Specieslevel<-Specieslevel[-Allium,]
```

Lo cual estaría bien, te estaría eliminando las filas dónde `Taxa=="Allium"`, el problema es que luego de esto se invalidan los siguientes vectores, ya que ahora `Specieslevel` tiene menos observaciones/filas y la siguiente eliminación, seguramente está eliminando cualquier otra fila.

Hay varias formas de resolverlo, siguiendo tu criterio, podrías combinar los tres vectores en uno solo y eliminar todo de una sola vez:

```
Specieslevel[-c(Allium,Amaranthus,Anacyclus),]
```

También, podrías evitar el uso de los vectores temporales, haciendo directamente:

```
Specieslevel<-Specieslevel[Specieslevel$Taxa!="Allium",]
Specieslevel<-Specieslevel[Specieslevel$Taxa!="Amaranthus",]
Specieslevel<-Specieslevel[Specieslevel$Taxa!="Anacyclus",]
```

o también todo en una sola instrucción

```
Specieslevel<-Specieslevel[!(Specieslevel$Taxa %in% c("Allium","Amaranthus","Anacyclus")),]
```

Comment: Patricio, ¡FUNCIONA!, muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta